# Implement one column to reference at many tables

Tags: sql

[image]

This is a part of a database that I am trying to complete. The database consists of data for a printing store, apart from keeping data for the customers the database must store the products available. The problem is that, each product has different characteristics, e.x. a lighter has different materials and lighting methods etc but a flyer has different paper qualities, colors to be used etc, so each product must be specified in another table. How can all these tables be connected through the "Order_Products" table? But I do not want to use references on the product tables("Product_01" etc)back to the "Order_Products" table.

Comment: You do not have to have a separate table for each product.  You can have PRODUCT_PROPERTY and PROPERTY_VALUES tables.

Comment: But then  for example a lighter would be able to have paper quality properties, no? Moreover, how can this be implemented?

Comment: PRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME)
00001 SOME_PAPER
00002 SOME_LIGHTER

PRODUCT_PROPERTY (PRODUCT_PROPERTY_ID, PRODUCT_PROPERTY_NAME)
00001    SOME_PAPER_PROPERTY
00002    SOME_LIGHTER_PROPERTY

PRODUCT_PROPERTY_VALUES (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_PROPERTY_ID, PRODUCT_PROPERTY_VALUE)
00002    00001 'Some Lighter Property Value'
00001    00002 'Some Paper Property Value'

Comment: @KevinPostlewaite thank you very much

Comment: Your welcome: just adding details to what @PM 77 proposed. Hope it was helpful.